# Error using if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, statistics

I am trying to define a new matrix `z` based  on another matrix `x`. This is what I did :

```
x = structure(
  .Data = c(5012, 3257,2638,-898,1734,2642,1828,599,-54,172,
            -106,4179,-1111,5270,3116,1817,-103,0,535,NA,
            3410,5582,4881,2268,2594,3479,0,603,NA, NA,
            5655,5900,4211,5500,2159,2658,984, NA, NA, NA,
            1092,8473,6271,6333,3786,-225, NA, NA, NA, NA,
            1513,4932,5257,1233,2917, NA , NA, NA, NA, NA,
            -557,3463,6926,1368, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
            1351,5596,6165, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
            3133,2262, NA, NA, NA , NA , NA , NA, NA , NA,
            2063, NA, NA, NA , NA , NA , NA, NA , NA, NA),
  .Dim = c(10,10))

x = t(x)
r=ncol(x)
z = matrix(ncol = r, nrow = r)
for(i in 1:r){
  for(j in 1:r){
    if(x[i,j]>0){
      z[i,j] = 1
    }
    else if(x[i,j]<0){
      z[i,j] = -1
    }
    else {
      z[i,j]=0
    }
  }
}
```

but I got error :

```
Error in if (x[i, j] > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: We can't compare NA values, try this small example: `if(NA){ "yes NA" } else { "no NA"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happened when `if` hit NA

```
for(i in 1:r){
   for(j in 1:r){
if(!is.na(x[i,j]) & x[i,j]>0){
  z[i,j] = 1
}
else if(!is.na(x[i,j]) & x[i,j]<0){
  z[i,j] = -1
}
else {
  z[i,j]=0
  }
 }
}
```